# It's possible to use iframe with vscode.dev on my webapp

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, iframe

I'm developing (web app) project manager and I want to know if it's possible to integrate vscode.dev or github.dev with iframe to edit some code inside my app without leave it.

User is **login with GitHub**, so he has access to her allowed repository from my app

Do you have an idea to do this or alternative solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** load vscode.dev in an iframe no matter what you do. I believe that the server is configured not to allow the site to be embedded on other websites.